# Format DateTime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I know this is an old problem but I cannot figure out why.

I have 2 voids binding in 2 buttons **GENERATE** and **SAVE**:

```
private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(textstarteddate.Text);
        DateTime enddate = new DateTime (startdate.Year, 12, 31);
        Int64 addedDays = Convert.ToInt64(textdaycount.Text);
        string taskID = texttaskID.Text;
        string machine = cb_machineID.Text.Trim();
        string note = texttasknote.Text;
        string runningtime = RMT.Text;
        string period = cb_periodID.Text.Trim();
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Maintenance Date", typeof(DateTime)));
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TaskID", typeof(String)));
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Machine", typeof(String)));
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Note", typeof(String)));
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Period", typeof(String)));
        _dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Running Time", typeof(String)));
        _dtdate.Rows.Clear();
        G1.DataBindings.Clear();
        if (cb_typescheID.Text == "Fix Date")
        {
            do
            {
                _dtdate.Rows.Add(startdate.Date, taskID, machine, note, period);
                startdate = startdate.AddDays(addedDays);
                G1.Refresh();
                //DateTime end = startdate;
            }
            while (startdate <= enddate);
        }
        G1.DataSource = _dtdate;
        G1.Columns["Maintenance Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
}
```

and

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (cb_typescheID.Text == "Fix Date")
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in _dtdate.Rows)
                    {                          
                        sqlstr = sqlstr + " INSERT INTO [PerformTask] (Year, Date, TasKID, MachineID, PerformStatus, ScheduleID, PeriodID) Values ('" + startdate.Year + "', '" + dr["Maintenance Date"].ToString() + "',";               
                        sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + texttaskID.Text.Trim() + "', '" + machine + "', 'RS_Open', '" + typeschedule + "', '" + period + "')";
                        G1.Columns["Maintenance Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";

                    }
                }
}
```

I tried every way to convert it to only Date (dd/MM/yyyy) but it still display on a DataGridView(G1) but when i try to save it into my datatable in SQL, its format is still "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" no matter how i convert it. I have read to old topic about this problem, tried their ways but still cannot save the data the way I want.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the Column as string:

```
_dtdate.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Maintenance Date", typeof(String)));
```

and then format the date when adding a new row:

```
_dtdate.Rows.Add(startdate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), taskID, machine, note, period);
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, just addition info, instead of `startdate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`, you could use `startdate.Date.ToShortDateString()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is not displaying the date in date format within the grid, but has to do with the format in SQL?
Is your database field date or datetime (assuming we are MS SQL Server)?  If you do not need the time information, it is much better to change the field to date.  It is much to be preferred to store dates as dates rather than as strings, since you can perform operations on them as dates, without having to cast.  In general, you should never be concerned with the way your database formats values; it is up to your presentation layer to handle formatting; your database should just concern itself with the efficient storing of data, and not worry about how that data looks.